# How to substitute canned Apricots with fresh when cooking

Tags: substitutions

My recipe calls for canned apricots, but I have fresh.  What do I need to co to make sure the recipe is successful.

Comment: Welcome Carmaletta, if you share the recipe you are using you are more likely to get  better answers.

Answer (score 2):

If the apricots are just a topping or mix-in, you might actually like it better with fresh than with canned, no need to change anything. Won't be the same, but that's not a bad thing! If they were supposed to have been canned with syrup, you'd want to add sugar to compensate.

If it seems like it's important for them to be a little softened, then you could cook them briefly in water, to do basically what canning does to them. (There's no need to actually can them in order to get that effect.) Something like 30 seconds to a couple minutes in boiling water, depending how soft you want them, and you can always add sugar afterwards to get them to the sweetness you want.

As an in-between option, you could also macerate them: toss them with sugar and let them sit for a while. That'll soften them and draw a lot of the juices out.

Answer (score -4):

Can the fresh apricots, then use the canned apricots.

Comment: Seriously? That's a witty comment, not an answer, right? (And yes, as it stands, the question is pretty vague.)

Comment: As it stands, it is a douchey but entirely accurate answer, the only one valid without knowing the recipe at all - which might be canned apricots on top of a custard for all we know.

Comment: So, are you going to start answering all the questions about substituting ingredients by saying "don't, go to the store and buy the thing you actually need"?

Comment: I understand that the question is vague. However, that doesn't really justify a snarky non-answer. The Be Nice policy applies everywhere on the site, even on vague questions, so if you end up defending your own answer as "douchey but accurate", you're probably not headed in the right direction.